# how to get loaded path of lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular

These are my routes

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'path1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.module').then(r => r.ChildModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'path2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./child/child.module').then(r => r.ChildModule),
  }]
```

I'd like to get "path1" or "path2" in constructor of ChildModule

```js
export class ChildModule { 
  constructor(router: Router) {
    // I'd like to get them here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ActivatedRoute** insted of **Router** to access activated route properties.

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

export class ChildModule { 
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams;
    this.route.params;
    this.route.data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.router.url` will return you the full path `/.../path1`. If there is no parent to the route then just `/path1` would be returned.

To return just the end of the path you can use

```
let path = this.router.url.split('/').pop(0);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns the current activated url. It returns "/" when I start the page at /path1.